# How do you convert WMV to MP4?

Tags: video, convert, mp4, wmv

I have some small WMV files which I want to convert to MP4. How do you convert these without too many troubles?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1280120/43926

Comment: You can convert WMV to MP4 like this:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/309515/converting-from-wmv-to-mp4